# remove certain attributes from HTML tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

How can I remove certain attributes such as id, style, class, etc. from HTML code?

I thought I could use the [lxml.html.clean module](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html), but as it turned out I can only remove style attributes with `Clean(style=True).clean_html(code)`. I'd prefer not to use regular expressions for this task (attributes could change).

What I would like to have:

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

code = '<tr id="ctl00_Content_AdManagementPreview_DetailView_divNova" class="Extended" style="display: none;">'

cleaner = Cleaner(style=True, id=True, class=True)
cleaned = cleaner.clean_html(code)

print cleaned
'<tr>'
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cleaner.Cleaner.__call__` has a `safe_attrs_only` parameter. When set to `True`, only attributes in `clean.defs.safe_attrs` are preserved. You can remove any or all attributes by changing `clean.defs.safe_attrs`. Just be sure to change it back when you are done.

```
import lxml.html.clean as clean

code = '<tr id="ctl00_Content_AdManagementPreview_DetailView_divNova" class="Extended" style="display: none;">'

safe_attrs = clean.defs.safe_attrs
cleaner = clean.Cleaner(safe_attrs_only=True, safe_attrs=frozenset())
cleansed = cleaner.clean_html(code)

print(cleansed)
```

yields

```
<tr></tr>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this technique to work in lxml-3.2.3.  Happen to know if they changed something?

Comment: To get it work in v3.2.3 I had to add `cleaner.safe_attrs = clean.defs.safe_attrs` after `cleaner = clean.Cleaner(...)`.

Comment: @Xavi: Thanks for the info. This is great news. It turns out `clean.Cleaner` now has (at least as of version 3.2.0) a per-instance `safe_attrs` attribute, so the old module-manipulating workaround is no longer necessary. Even better, the `safe_attrs` can be set upon instantiation.