# Remove all the attributes of every node in an XML document

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a Node(element) object of an XML Document. I need to remove all the attributes of it's and it's Sub Nodes. How do i do this in python? i'm using `xml.dom.minidom`

Comment: Is your aim to output a new xml document that is a copy of the input but without attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove certain attributes from HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470333/remove-certain-attributes-from-html-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(document)

for node in dom.childNodes:
    if node.attributes:
        for key in node.attributes.keys():
            node.removeAttribute(key)
```

Comment: this will help. i think i should recursively do this to all the element nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Rob's answer won't work nowadays, it will cause a `RunTimeError` when you try to remove a `key`from a `dict` you are using as an`Iterator`

So, before trying to remove you should clone the keys first, something like this would work

```
keys = list(xml_node.attributes.keys()) if xml_node.attributes else []
for attribute in keys:
    xml_node.removeAttribute(attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is easy to do with [PyQuery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/), it has a remove attribute method: http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html#pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery.removeAttr